# How can I exclude libraries in a WAR during jQAssistant scan?

Tags: jqassistant

I'm new to jQAssistant, and I like it very much. However, I'm not interested in having any data of dependencies outside our company in the Neo4j database.

So far, I haven't found any means to exclude JARs from being scanned when they're found in a WAR's lib directory.

Am I missing something?

Or as an alternative: Can I remove all the data that's not coming from our code from the Neo4j database?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very experimental (and therefore not yet documented) property for the file scanner plugin that allows filtering files during scan but functionality is quite limited. Assuming that you're scanning using the command line utility:

1. Create a file scan.properties with the following content:

`file.include=*.war,*.jar,/org/springframework/**`

The first pattern includes your WAR file, the second all contained jar files (within the WAR), the last one your desired packages (in this case org.springframework).

2. Execute the CLI

`jqassistant -p scan.properties -f application.war`

The alternative (i.e. deleting all nodes from JARs that you're not interested in) is not feasible, as it would turn out to be a quite expensive query.

But it could make sense to think the other way round: just add a label to all the JAR archives that you're interested in, e.g.

`MATCH
  (jar:Jar)
WHERE
  jar.fileName starts with "/WEB-INF/lib/spring-"
SET
  jar:Internal
RETURN
  jar.fileName`

Then you can use that label in queries for your Java types:

`MATCH
  (:Internal:Jar)-[:CONTAINS]->(type:Type)
RETURN
  type.fqn`