# How to configure jQAssistant to exclude specific directories from the scan?

Tags: jqassistant

I'm using jqassistant-commandline-neo4jv4-2.1.0 and I would like to configure .jqassistant.yml
to exclude specific dir(s) when scanning.

I have tried the following:

```
jqassistant:
  scan:
    include:
        files:
        - "!/BOOT-INF/lib/**"
        - "!**/lib/**"
```

but it did not work, I'm still seeing the follwing log when I run the scan:

```
2024-03-21 15:04:56.867 [main] INFO AbstractContainerScannerPlugin - Entering /BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar
2024-03-21 15:04:56.868 [main] INFO AbstractContainerScannerPlugin - Leaving /BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar (3 entries, 0 ms)
2024-03-21 15:04:56.869 [main] INFO AbstractContainerScannerPlugin - Entering /BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar
2024-03-21 15:04:56.869 [main] INFO AbstractContainerScannerPlugin - Leaving /BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar (3 entries, 0 ms)
2024-03-21 15:04:56.883 [main] INFO AbstractContainerScannerPlugin - Entering /BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar
....
.....
....
```

Also, the answer reported here: [How can I exclude libraries in a WAR during jQAssistant scan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49156724/how-can-i-exclude-libraries-in-a-war-during-jqassistant-scan) does not work, since the jqassistant-commandline-neo4jv4-2.1.0 does not have "-p" which I tried to replace with -C but still did not work with the following in the scan.properties:
file.include=!/BOOT-INF/lib/*,!/lib/*
and
file.exclude=/BOOT-INF/lib/*,/lib/*

Answer (score 0):

As of jQAssistant 2.x the parameter `-p` has been replaced by a configuration property in `.jqassistant.yml`, thus you can apply the solution from the referenced SO question:

```
jqassistant:
  scan:
    properties:
      file.include: "*.war,*.jar,/org/springframework/**"
```

You can as well specify a property `file.exlude` that is applied after evaluating `file.include`.

Comment: Note that there's afeature request for improved support for using file patterns, see https://github.com/jQAssistant/jqa-core-framework/issues/87.

Comment: Do I understand it correct, I need to specify both file.include and once it scans all the included it will remove the once which I have specified in the file.exlude ?
So if I have specified the following:
jqassistant:
  scan:
    properties:
      file.include: "*.jar"
      file.exlude: "/BOOT-INF/lib/**"

It will scan all the jars and once it scans the included it will remove the once which are scanned and are in the excluded?

If this is the case, I have tried it and it does not work.
It is also not working when I specify only the excluded

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working setup, tested on a Spring Boot generated JAR-File:

```
jqassistant:
  scan:
    include:
      files:
        - hexagonal-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    properties:
      file.exclude: /BOOT-INF/lib/**
```